# post status on facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am implementing an app in which user will be able to post status. If user is default login in his/her device then following code will work

```
  if(!self.accountStore)
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil)
{
    ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [self.accountStore 
    accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:@"com.apple.facebook"];
    NSLog(@"facebookTypeAccount..:%@",facebookTypeAccount);
    NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
    if (facebookTypeAccount) {
        if ([accounts respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]) {
            [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                                       options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"214267482030378", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]}
                                                    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                                        if(granted){
                                                            NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                                            _facebookAccount = [[accounts lastObject]retain];
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            NSLog(@"Failed, Error: %@", error);
                                                        }
                                                    }];
        }
        else
        {
            [self openSession];
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise control will go to this method

```
- (void)openSession{
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"publish_stream",@"email",
                        nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                      allowLoginUI:YES
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
 {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

 }];
```

}

But with login I need to send status on Facebook. If I tried with this method

```
   -(void)poststatus{
[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:@[ @"publish_stream" ]  
defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone completionHandler:^(FBSession 
*authSession, NSError *authError) {
    // If auth was successful, create a status update FBRequest
    if (!authError) {
        FBRequest *postRequest = [FBRequest requestForPostStatusUpdate:@"Hello, world!"];
        [postRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            // TODO: Check for success / failure here
        }];
    }
}];
```

}

then it gives the error Failed, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 8.)" Please help me out if anyone has some idea regarding this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for:

```
@[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"]
```

Instead of just:

```
@[ @"publish_stream" ]
```

Read more:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

```
publish_stream  The publish_stream permission is required to post to a Facebook Page's timeline. For a Facebook User use publish_actions.
```

Also you are using deprecated function. Try with:

```
[FBSession requestNewPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:completionHandler:];
```

Comment: One more tip in my answer - you are using deprecated method.

Comment: I tested this code on my app - it works. Maybe you have some problems with application settings ? Are you working in Sandbox ?

Comment: I have resolved this issue by implementing this http://pastebin.com/d8jcCk33 @Grzegorz Krukowski but really thanks for your support :)

Comment: No problem. I'm quite sure that anyways you need @publish_actions to make it work.

Comment: I have just added email permissions dear @Grzegorz Krukowski